# mongodb insert multiple documents if they don't exist otherwise do nothing

Tags: mongodb, insert, not-exists

I want to store tags that users input freeform so I can offer them as suggestions when other users input tags.

How can I insert all the new tags a user has input only where the tag doesn't already exist in my suggestions collection?

For example I have an array like this of tags that a user input:

```
[
   {"name": "tag 1"}, 
   {"name": "tag 2"}, 
   {"name": "tag 3"},
   {"name": "tag 4"},
   {"name": "tag 5"}
]
```

And the collection I'm inserting to has these documents already.

```
{ _id: <IDHERE>, "name": "tag 2" }
{ _id: <IDHERE>, "name": "tag 4" }
{ _id: <IDHERE>, "name": "tag 5" }
```

I want to end up with the collection having all these records like this:

```
{ _id: <IDHERE>, "name": "tag 1" }
{ _id: <IDHERE>, "name": "tag 2" }
{ _id: <IDHERE>, "name": "tag 3" }
{ _id: <IDHERE>, "name": "tag 4" }
{ _id: <IDHERE>, "name": "tag 5" }
```

Is there a way with a single statement to pass the array above to that collection and have it insert `{"name": "tag 1"}` and `{"name": "tag 3"}` and ignore the others since they already exist.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is possible with single query, you can try `upsert` in update command, example in js/nodejs,

- iterate loop of tags array and update query by checking name and set name,

```
let tags = [{"name": "tag 1"}, {"name": "tag 2"}, {"name": "tag 3"}, {"name": "tag 4"}, {"name": "tag 5"}];

tags.forEach(function(tag) {
  db.collection.updateOne(
    { name: tag.name }, 
    { $set: { name: tag.name } },
    { upsert: true }
  )
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Oce-sGScHQU)

---

You can use [bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) method,

```
let bulkTags = [];

tags.forEach(function(tag) {
  bulkTags.push({
    updateOne: {
      filter: { name: tag.name },
      update: { $set: { name: tag.name } },
      upsert: true
    }
  });
});

db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkTags);
```

Comment: bulkWrite is what I was missing. Worked great. Thank you.